# JIRA REST API oAuth returns signature invalid

Tags: laravel, rest, oauth, jira

I am using a [Client](https://github.com/alexzv/jira-restapi-client) I found on GitHub to use JIRA'S REST API and authorize with oAuth. JIRA returns invalid signature. This is my code:

```
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use App\Jira\JiraClient;

 class RestAPIController extends BaseController
 {
     use DispatchesJobs;
     public function get()
     {
       $config['base_url']= env('JIRA_ADRESS');
       $config['private_key']= app_path().env('PRIVATE_KEY');
       $config['consumer_key']= env('CONSUMER_KEY');
       $config['consumer_secret']= app_path().env('CONSUMER_SECRET');
       $config['callback_url']= env('CALLBACK');
       $client = new JiraClient($config);
       $client->init();
       //$issue = $client -> getIssue('TP-115');
       return view('issue',['issue' => $issue]);
     }
 }
```

This is the error returned:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gU1D.jpg) 
I use these properties:

```
JIRA_ADRESS=localhost:8015/
PRIVATE_KEY=\Jira\Api\Authentication\jira.pem
CONSUMER_SECRET=qwerty123
CONSUMER_KEY=hardcoded-consumer
CALLBACK=http://localhost:8000/get
```

Comment: looking at the repo and seeing the last commit was over 4 years ago give me the suspision it might be autdated / broken

Comment: @ThomasMoors That was one of my concerns, but i read through it, and it "looked like", everything is fine ( though i am new at oAuth requests)

Comment: What about using this one: https://github.com/univerze/laravel-jira

Comment: That one uses Basic authentication, I managed to make one without any Clients, but i require to make one with oAuth.